# Finding the time between now and at specific time using swift 3

Tags: swift, time

I am trying to find the time (in seconds) between now and a specific time during that day e.g 9:00 AM and if the time now is past this specified time in the day, I would want the time between now and that set time in the next day.

My ultimate goal is to run a function at every hour from 8:00 AM to 5:00 PM, while the application is not open/ in background. If there is a better way to do this without using a timer with an interval of 24 hours then I would really appreciate some suggestions.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read the documentation on `NSDate` /  `Date`?

Comment: what do you want to do? finding time interval? or run a function every hour?

Comment: Im trying to run a function every hour (between set hours), I am trying to go about this by finding the time until one of these hours and then running `Date().addingTimeInterval(timeUntilXTime)` followed by a Timer. If there is a better way to do it I am very willing to change my method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For adding an hour to the current time. Use the below extension

```
extension Date {
  func addHours(_ hours: Int) -> Date {
    let seconds: TimeInterval = Double(hours) * 60 * 60
    let newDate: Date = self.addingTimeInterval(seconds)
    return newDate
  }
}
```

call this function as `Date().addHours(1)`

To get specific time of current date

```
func getDateFromHour(hour: Int) -> Date {
  let date = Date()
  let calendar = Calendar.current
   et componentsCurrent = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)

  var components = DateComponents()
  components.hour = hour
  components.minute = 0
  components.second = 0
  components.month = componentsCurrent.month
  components.day = componentsCurrent.day
  components.year = componentsCurrent.year
  return calendar.date(from: components)!
}
```

Note: you should use 24-hour clock while passing the parameter **hour**.

Comment: how would I call this function at a specific time though. e.g. 12:00PM

Comment: glad i could help :)